# Variant of the same theme for each page

Tags: themes

I have a wp site with seven books, each book has a page, and each page will have the same structure, but differents style ( Each book has his own color guide).

So, what I need is apply a different variant of the same theme for each page...

Is it posible? How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be to add it to a CSS style.

WP output body classes, which allow to precisely target any specific page with CSS by ID, for example:

```
<body class="page page-id-7 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support group-blog no-sidebar">
```

While it's not default I also like to hook into it and add `page-[name]` class for myself.

If your theme is custom you can just work styling into it. If you are using off the shelf theme you should probably create a child theme for it and implement custom styles there.

Comment: ok, so solution is using 1 child theme theme, and define 1 style set for each page am I right?

Comment: Correct, that should work nicely.

Comment: ok! I will try it! Tx for your help!